# How do I convert an object of object to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My object looks like this { {},{},{},{} }

I want it to look like this:

[ {},{},{},{} ]

Comment: Do you want to loose the property names for the inner objects in the original object? Because the original object cannot be the way you described. It has to be `{foo:{}, bar:{}, baz:{}}`.

Comment: where are the keys for your original object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can use the $.each() method to loop through the original object.

Otherwise, you can try a for loop:

```js
var originalObject = { 
    "key1": { "obj1Key": "obj1Value" },
    "key2": { "obj2Key": "obj2Value" },
    "key3": { "obj3Key": "obj3Value" } 
}

var newArray = [];

for (var key in originalObject) {
    newArray.push(originalObject[key]);
}

console.log("New Array: " + newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

IF you are on Chrome or Firefox only, you can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
var o = {a:{k:1}, b:{k:2}, c:{k:3}}
var values = Object.values(o);
// [{"k":1}, {"k":2}, {"k":3}]
```

Otherwise, use (and accept) an answer based on `Object.keys()`.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd advise OP that this won't work on Safari, IE, Edge and Opera.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Good idea.

Comment: I'm trying to find any information regarding Edge, but I can't find any... So, to give the benefit of the doubt, let's say for now that `Object.values()` doesn't work on: Safari, Opera and IE (does anything work on IE???).

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all there is no such thing as an object of objects unless you mean an object which properties are objects. Example: `{ foo: { bar: 'xyz'} }`.

To convert such object into a collection (array of objects) just loop through the keys like such

```
let objOfObjs = {
  foo: { xyz: 'bar'},
  bar: { abc: 'foo'}
}, collection = [];

Object.keys(objOfObjs).forEach(key => collection.push(objOfObjs[key]));

console.log(collection); //[ { xyz: 'bar' }, { abc: 'foo' } ]
```

Repl: https://repl.it/I4MS

Comment: `collection = Object.keys (objOfObjs).map (key => objOfObjs[key]);` ?

Comment: @HBP True, I rather do it the way I posted simply because I don't like doing that sort of logic in variable declarations.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = { 'a' : {}, 'b': {}, 'c': {}, 'd': {} }
var list = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    list.push(obj[key]);
});
```

or simpler

```
   var list = Object.values(obj);
```